# Push key value in empty array using php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-push, array-walk

I have associative array and value related with that key  contain json_encoded data so I converted it and it resulted in array,I am using array_walk to iterate each array value than and printing values using foreach loop  but at same time I want to push (key and values) in empty array which is declared outside but it is not inserting any value.

Note: Here `$result` is associative array and its key contain value which is json data, i don't want to use nested foreach loop so used array_walk()

```
$new_array=array();

array_walk($result, function(&$a, &$key) use($i) {

    $var = '';
    foreach (json_decode($a) as $row_key => $row_value) {

        if ($row_key == 'abc') {
            $new_array[$row_key][] = array(    // push key,value in $new_array
                $row_key => $row_value,
            );
        } else {

           echo $row_key . " : " . $row_value ;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use** `$new_array` by reference:

```
array_walk($result, function(&$a, &$key) use($i, &$new_array) {
```

Also, I don't see any sense in passing `$a` and `$key` by reference. Maybe, you show us not full code, and passing by reference `$a` and `$key` has sense, but currently, you don't even use `$key` in the code.

What's the purpose of passing it then?

```
// probably:
array_walk($result, function($a) use($i, &$new_array) {
```

Comment: thank you som much you saved  me,  greate work ,can u please tell me why $new_array should be passed by reference

Comment: Passing by reference means that __original value__ of variable will be changed. This is just what you need - chnage the original value. On the contrary - passing __by value__ just passes value and does not change the original value.